# Accessing associative arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I want to access the index 'memo' in the associative array in PHP below

```
$variables["thelistitems"];
print_r($variables["thelistitems"]);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [productid] => prod:c6dbdd62-dc13-6421-5a94-c8cd871a59d3 
        [memo] => dummy 
        [taxable] => 0 
        [unitweight] => 0 
        [unitcost] => 450.02 
        [unitprice] => 445.02 
        [quantity] => 1
    )
)
```

Comment: ....and what's the question about this? What have you tried to achieve that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What you essentially have is an array of associative arrays.  So to access the first memo, it's

```
 $variables["thelistitems"][0]["memo"]
```

To access each memo, you'd do something like this

```
foreach($variables["thelistitems"] as $listitem) {
    $memo = $listitem["memo"];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you want this ?

```
$variables["thelistitems"][0]['memo']
```