# How to pass array with query string in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have to pass an associative array of email with the query string.

Please tell me how can I pass array with query string and how can I access the array element from there.

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff. Try watching a tutorial or something. For entertainment’s sake, you can access an array value by doing `$array[key]`. Where key is the index. This doesn't take into account multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `http_build_query()` which also supports multi-dimensional arrays.

Simple example:

```
$a["one"] = "Bob";
$a["two"] = "Alice";
$a["three"] = "John";

echo http_build_query($a);
```

The above example will output:

```
one=Bob&two=Alice&three=John
```

Answer (score 0):

if you `print_r($array_name)`

is show array structer

```
  Array
  (
      [0] => Array
      (
          [id] => 007
          [name] => Abdulla 
          [online] => yes        
      )
  )
```

if you want access those

```
  echo $variables["array_name"][0]["name"]; //this will show the data

  foreach($variables["array_name"] as $item) 
  {
      $id = $item["id"];
      $name = $item["name"];
      $online = $item["online"];
  }
```

read this [Answer As well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3842124/4595675)

To attch in email

```
  $to = '';//email address
  $subject = ''//subject here
  $message = 'Name : '.$name.'online : '.$online;    

  mail($to, $subject, $message)//send mail
```