# how to read values from an assosiative array using php?

Tags: php, arrays

This is my sample associative array:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [Name] => ALCOIN
        [BasePlugin] => HTTP
        [Version] => 1
        [Description] => Plugin for ALCO_IN operations
        [ImagePath] => ./resources
        [xip] => http://www.example.org/XIP
        [xsi] => http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
        [schemaLocation] => http://www.example.org/XIP XIP.xsd
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [xip:Action] => Array (
            [@attributes] => Array (
                [Name] => OfferActivationByOfferID
                [Version] => 1.0
                [ImagePath] => ./resources
            )
        )
    )
)
```

In that array I need to get the `BasePlugin` value and the name `attribute` value.

Comment: Please do some formatting on your code, this is not readable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing associative arrays in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842111/accessing-associative-arrays-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are assigned to `$yourVar` like:

```
$yourVar = Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [Name] => ALCOIN
        [BasePlugin] => HTTP
        [Version] => 1
        [Description] => Plugin for ALCO_IN operations
        [ImagePath] => ./resources
        [xip] => http://www.example.org/XIP
        [xsi] => http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
        [schemaLocation] => http://www.example.org/XIP XIP.xsd
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [xip:Action] => Array (
            [@attributes] => Array (
                [Name] => OfferActivationByOfferID
                [Version] => 1.0
                [ImagePath] => ./resources
            )
        )
    )
)
```

You would use:

```
echo $yourVar[0]["BasePlugin"];
echo $yourVar[1]["xip:Action"]["@attributes"]["Name"];
echo $yourVar[1]["xip:Action"]["@attributes"]["Version"];
echo $yourVar[1]["xip:Action"]["@attributes"]["ImagePath"];
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems you might need this:

```
$basePlugin = $yourArray[0]['BasePlugin'];
$attributes = $yourArray[1]['xip:Action']['@attributes'];
```